# VBA Copy and Paste Table as Picture from Excel to Word using Content Controls

Tags: excel, vba

The following VBA code copies from excel a named range for a table as a picture and paste it into a word document as a picture using content controls. The content control name is the same as the named range in excel. The following snippet of code works.

Is there a way to make this code faster or more efficient?

```
Set tTable = Range(CCtrl.Title)
tTable.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

Set wdbmRange = wdDoc.ContentControls(CCtrl.ID)
If Occ.Type = wdContentControlPicture Then
    If Occ.Range.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then Occ.Range.InlineShapes(1).Delete
    wdDoc.ContentControls(CCtrl.ID).Range.Paste
```

Comment: Because your code is working, this is probably more a question for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). But I guess there is not much space to improve that code.

Comment: Thank you Peh.  I will review Code Review Stack Exchange.